# Move constructor not calling destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, move

My understanding is that the destructor is called on the input after the call to the move constructor.  I decided to test this in code (see bottom), but get different results from what I expected.  I get the same results using `std::unique_ptr`.

**Expected:**

```
1
2
bar constructed
foo destructed //due to move
3
i'm foo
4
[Error?]
```

**Actual:**

```
1
2
bar constructed
3
i'm foo
4
i'm foo
5
foo destructed
foo destructed
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  ~Foo()
  {
    std::cout << "foo deconstructed" << std::endl;
  }
  void speak()
  {
    std::cout << "i'm foo" << std::endl;
  }
};

class Bar
{
public:
  Bar(Foo&& foo) : foo_(std::move(foo))
  {
    std::cout << "bar constructed" << std::endl;
  }
  Foo foo_;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
  Foo foo;
  std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
  Bar bar(std::move(foo));
  std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
  bar.foo_.speak();
  std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
  foo.speak();
  std::cout << "5" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My understanding is that the destructor is called on the input after the call to the move constructor

Your understanding is incorrect.  Nothing about move semantics or C++11 changes when destructors get called.  Nothing has changed here - foo's destructor gets called at the end of `main` in this case.

Your confusion probably stems from the fact that in many cases it appears as though the destructor is called immediately after the move constructor.

For example, if you were to create a `Bar` with an rvalue: `Bar bar(Foo{});` the destructor of `Foo` would run right after `Bar`'s move constructor.  This isn't because there's a move constructor though - it's because the lifetime of the temporary `Foo` object has ended.

Comment: `Bar bar(Foo())` does not create a `Bar`.

Comment: So basically a move constructor is nothing more than shallow-copy constructor?

Comment: @anon shallow-copy and also remove the resource handles from the source

Comment: `Bar bar((Foo()))` could also be used to avoid [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Answer (score 5):

The destructor is called on an object when its lifetime ends - for automatic storage duration objects, like `foo`, this happens when they go out of scope. For static storage duration objects, this happens when the program exits. For temporaries, this happens either

1. At the end of the statement in which they were created - In `Foo foo = Foo();`, assuming no copy elision, the temporary created by `Foo()` is destroyed.
2. When a reference that this temporary was bound to is destroyed - In `{const Foo& foo = Foo(); doStuff();}`, the temporary is destroyed when the scope ends(`}`).

None of these criteria have anything to do with the move constructor. While not mandated, move constructors usually leave the object that was moved out of in a valid state.